# Drupal View Filter Criteria "Contains Taxonomy"

Tags: views

I need to filter based on taxonomy term in my view, I have set up this filter however I would like to return nodes that 'contain', not "Is one of". See screenshot below:
[image: Views exposed filters]

Is there a module or a way I can achieve this? If I put 'vod' instead of 'vodafone' it does not return anthing:

[image: View returned results]

The end goal is to filter nodes from the URL e.g. localhost/numbers?field_company=vod will return nodes for vodafone and vodafoneblahblah.

Answer (score 2):

- Add a Relationship of type "Terms in node"
- Add a filter "Taxonomy term: Name"

Now you can set "Contains" has an option for your filter